# Wait until WebElement attribute contains specific value

Tags: python, selenium

I have got all the image tags by

```
image_tags = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//img')
```

however, the src of the images needs some time to change to the format of 'https://....'. So here is what I got now

```
for image_tag in image_tags:
  WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(** this image's src contains 'http' **) # how to write this part?
  url = image_tag.get_attribute('src') # get the real url address
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, combine this answer [[Create custom wait until condition in Python]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53887433/4997273) with @OT413's answer, problem solved

```
 WebDriverWait(self.browser, 60).until(lambda wd: "http" in img_tag.get_attribute('src'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selector and `WebDriverWait` to wait until `img` with `src` attribute begins with **https**:

```
image_tags = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[src^='https']")))
for image_tag in image_tags:
    print(image_tag.get_attribute("src"))
```

Comment: Can you illustrate what does "img[^='https']" mean please?

Comment: It should be `img[src^='https']`. img tag with src attribute begins with https, details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until("https://" in image_tag.get_attribute('src'))
```

Comment: Tried, not working. TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable