# Wait for text in an element to be a number in Selenium with Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, wait, expected-condition

A dynamically generated website has such an element:

```
<b class="2020-is-terrible"></b>
```

After some time it fills the `b` element with a random number like this:

```
<b class="2020-is-terrible">42</b>
```

I want to wait for that number to be generated and for now I've come up a code that waits for a specific number:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CLASS_NAME, "2020-is-terrible"), "42"))
```

But I want to continue if any value appears in the `b` element (not just 42). The value will always be a number so I just need to check if the text not empty.

List of [expected_conditions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html) classes so you don't need to google.

Comment: I'm not a Python guy, so I do not know the correct syntax, but did you tried to check if the fetched text is not empty and is numeric? You can do that in `until` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With xpath you can also use the **`and`** operator by combine class name and `text!=''`, like this:

`//b[@class='2020-is-terrible' and text()!='']`

Try this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//b[@class='2020-is-terrible' and text()!='']")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked for me:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda wd: wd.find_element_by_class_name("threat-score").text != "")
```

My mistake was assuming that I have to use one of the `expected_conditions` classes in `until`.

Thanks to Jonah for the hint and Dmytro Serdiuk for [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420957/create-custom-wait-until-condition-in-python).